# selenium webdriver - wait until google map all tiles loaded

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gwt, testng-eclipse

I'm new to selenium and I'm kind of stuck.
I'm automating GWT base application and I need to wait till map tiles are fully loaded before moving to next process.
I'm try to find in google but no luck.
I found something like

```
public static final void waitTillPageLoad()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(LoginTestScript.fd, 40);
        wait.until( new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        }
    );
    }
```

but, I need to wait untill map tiles loaded not `document.readyState` 
do anyone have idea how can I wait until all map tiles loaded successfully.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below method:

```
public boolean checkForPresenceOfElementByXpath(String xpath){
    try{
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(xpath)[last()]")));
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Remove the return type and return statements, if you dont want to return the values.

Comment: what do you mean by `By.xpath("(xpath)[last()]"`

Comment: (//div[@id='tiles'])[last()] - in which, [last()] identifies the last tile and waits for it to get loaded. (driver, 5) is waiting 5 seconds, you can increase as much you wanted